# Can blossom end rot appear on side of pepper?

Tags: peppers, blossom-end-rot

Some of my bell peppers have rotting spots that look like blossom end rot, but in each case, the rotten spot is high on the side of the pepper, nearer the stem than the end. Could this be blossom end rot? Or is it some other problem?

The weather has been perfect for causing blossom end rot (hot and dry, followed by days of heavy rain).

Update: See photo.[image: Bell pepper with rotten spot.]

Comment: please provide a photo

Comment: Did (or do) all the rotting spots face the same direction on the plant?

Comment: @Bamboo yes, they do seem to face a similar direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely isn't blossom end rot, although once rot has set in, you could be forgiven for wondering if it is! If the affected areas on the fruits all face the same direction, and from your description of weather conditions, the most likely causal explanation is sunscald or sunburn. If the plants have a good leaf canopy and most of the fruits are shaded by the leaves, then sunburn is less likely. Heavy rain can cause the fruits to grow more quickly, which renders them even more susceptible to sunscald  during very hot,sunny weather. The rot you see doesn't always happen, but often a patch of serious sunburn will start to rot. Shading during the middle of the day when temperatures are high and the sunlight is strong should help to alleviate the problem. More info here http://msue.anr.msu.edu/news/hot_and_sunny_days_promote_sunscald_in_peppers_and_other_vegetables

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense. Not only are all the spots facing SE, but it's also only affecting the plants on the SE edge of my garden, and only the fruits on the SE side of each plant. It's all very orderly.